# How to display all values in a facet block even when a value is active?

Tags: solr, solrj

I have facet block which looks like:

```
Categories:
[ ] Category 1
[ ] Category 2
[ ] Category 3
[ ] Category 4
```

Categories are represented with the ss_category field (single string field). When a category is selected, all the other categories disappear, which makes the block looks like:

```
Categories:
[X] Category 3
```

I need all the other categories to remain displayed even when there is an active category, so that the user doesn't have to unclick the active category first then click another one. In other words the block should look like:

```
Categories:
[ ] Category 1
[ ] Category 2
[X] Category 3
[ ] Category 4
```

How can I achieve this behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See [the example in LocalParams for faceting](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting#Faceting-LocalParametersforFaceting). This allow you to tag an `fq`, and then exclude that filter when creating the facets.

The example shows the exact same issue for file endings:

> q=mainquery&fq=status:public&fq={!tag=dt}doctype:pdf&facet=true&facet.field={!ex=dt}doctype

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of client you're using to query Solr, but if the query creation is not completely transparent to you, it is all about a filter query and the related facet field.

Just to be clear,when you add a filter query, it affects also the facets creation. What you have to do is exclude the filter query from facet creation. You can do this using a 2 steps syntax during query creation.

1. add to the filter query a tag, in your example you have to change

   `fq=Categories:"Category 3"` => `fq={!tag=categoryTag}Categories:"Category 3"`
2. then you can exclude the filter query from facet generation, so change

   `facet.field=Categories` => `facet.field={!ex=categoryTag}Categories`